# Can't connect to JSON file using AJAX

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I'm making a javascript web app that takes the user's input about what font the want to check out from the google fonts API. I can't seem to connect to the google fonts api. I'm using the default code they have on their developer site.

https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/developer_api

I'm trying to connect to this JSON file here

https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=AIzaSyCKDRrItgVcxrwi8AZwgqMnK4hyEC5tCoY

My AJAX code

```
function getFont(fontUrl) {

    var googleFontAPI = "https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=AIzaSyCKDRrItgVcxrwi8AZwgqMnK4hyEC5tCoY";

    $.getJSON(googleFontAPI, function (data) {
        var apiUrl = [];
        apiUrl.push('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=');
        apiUrl.push(anonymousPro.family.replace(/ /g, '+'));
        if (contains('italic', anonymousPro.variants)) {
            apiUrl.push(':');
            apiUrl.push('italic');
        }
        if (contains('greek', anonymousPro.subsets)) {
            apiUrl.push('&subset=');
            apiUrl.push('greek');
        }

        // url: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anonymous+Pro:italic&subset=greek'
        var url = apiUrl.join('');
        console.log(url);
    });
}
```

When I try to run the code it returns this error message

[image]

Comment: Where do you set the variable `anonymousPro`?

Comment: Are you intending to use the `data` variable anywhere?

Comment: If you look at the JSON, you'll see that `family`, `variants`, and `subsets` are properties of the objects in the `data.items` array. You need to loop through that array and do what you want with them.

Comment: Oh I didn't think i needed to set anonymousPro I thought it came from the array also im setting up the loop right now to see if i can get it to work

Comment: I wasn't looping it you were correct sir! Its now connected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should search in JSON result to see if font exist in Google font API,
then combine the information of variable "fontObject" (in your exemple called anonymousPro) to create a Fonts API request.

```
async function getFont(fontObject) {

        var googleFontAPI = "https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=AIzaSyCKDRrItgVcxrwi8AZwgqMnK4hyEC5tCoY";
        let url = null;
        await $.getJSON(googleFontAPI, function (data) {
            let result = data.items;

            if(result.filter( x => x.family === fontObject.family).length > 0){
                var apiUrl = [];
                apiUrl.push('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=');
                apiUrl.push(fontObject.family.replace(/ /g, '+'));
                if (fontObject.variants.includes('italic')) {
                    apiUrl.push(':');
                    apiUrl.push('italic');
                }
                if (fontObject.subsets.includes('greek')) {
                    apiUrl.push('&subset=');
                    apiUrl.push('greek');
                }
                // url: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anonymous+Pro:italic&subset=greek'
                url = apiUrl.join('');                  
            }
        });
        console.log(url)
        return url
    }

    let fontObject = {
            family: 'Anonymous Pro',
            variants: 'italic',
            subsets: 'greek'
        }

    getFont(fontObject).then(url => {
       console.log(url)
    })
```